# Определить кодировку

Tags: delphi, кодировка

Помогите правильно прочитать текст. При подключении(Delphi, Indy) к удаленному серверу(TCP) приходит строка(в ней есть как английские так и русские символы) приходит строка, в которой английские символы отображены правильно, а русский в виде черных ромбов с вопросительным знаком.[image]

Помогите правильно прочитать строки, спасибо.

Comment: Скорее всего utf8

Comment: Сервер обязан сообщать, в какой кодировке его ответ. Не стоит угадывать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это однозначно utf8. Какая версия Delphi?

```
TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(const Bytes: TBytes): string;
```

Засылаете туда полученные байтики, на выходе получаете обычную юникодную строку, которую можно выводить сразу в memo.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci мне нравятся выражения типа "обычная юникодная строка". Т.е. utf8 -- необычная, а utf16 -- обычная. Это дельфины такие умные, или винды влияют?

Comment: @alexlz под "обычная юникодная строка" я мел ввиду юникод, в котором делфи хранит у себя строки, когда мы пишем `s := 'bla-bla'` или `Button1.Caption := 'Превед!'`.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Спецы по виндам утверждают, что сейчас в виндах носят utf-16 (основная часть символов -- 2б, что не влазит -- 4б). То, что влезает в 2б, совпадает с прежней кодировкой ucs-2, которой utf-16 и пришла на смену.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Delphi XE5. Спасибо за помощь.